# Mapping Data Flows - Working with Dynamic Business Keys

Tags: azure-mapping-data-flow

I am building a parameterised Mapping dataflow pipeline and have run into a problem that I need help with.

My ADF Load is based on a config file, a sample of which is given below:

[image: Config File]

I would like the ability to join using the Stagekeys column in my config file using the EXISTS transformation shown below

[image: Mapping Data Flows here]

Any suggestions on how I can achieve it?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding was right we can parameterize key columns and prepare  Exists Expression.

FYI, attached condition for single key we can extend that with multi keys as "source1@keyColumn1 == source2@keyColumn1 && source1@keyColumn2 == source2@keyColumn2"

--**Dataflow Parameter**
[image: Dataflow Parameter]

--**Exists Expressions**
[image: Exists Condition]

For multiple keys from same target table can use following expression and send key columns as array

array(**byNames**($pKeyColumns,'sourceADLSCSV')) == array(**byNames**($pKeyColumns,'targetASQL'))

--**Pipeline  Parameter**
[image: Pipeline Parameter]

--**Dataflow Parameter**
[image: Dataflow Parameter*]

--**Exists Expressions**
[image]

Comment: Hi Suvarna, this may not work as the code only deals with a business key. I have multiple keys to consider for my JOIN. My keys are loaded into the mapping data flows as an array [a.b,c,d], and each of these columns in the array needs to be in my EXISTS JOIN.

Comment: Hi Sarath, is multiple join keys from multiple target able or same target table ?

Comment: Hi SuvarnaThe multiple key columns are from the same table

Comment: changing "byName" to "byNames" should work for multiple keys as array :
toString(byNames($pKeyColumns,'sourceADLSCSV')) == toString(byNames($pKeyColumns,'targetASQL'))

Comment: Hi Suvarna, you get the following error when attempting that. Function 'toString' does not take 5 arguments

Comment: No Sarath, let me try for 5 or more keys then get back to you.

Comment: Hi Sarath, tested it seems 'toSting' has issue with 5 or more fields better to use 'array';  i.e., "array(byNames($pKeyColumns,'sourceADLSCSV')) == array(byNames($pKeyColumns,'targetASQL'))"

Comment: In addition 'toString' function only can convert a primitive datatype to a string.